# How to parse markdown to HTML tree in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, markdown

I want to parse **markdown** to **HTML** tree in Node.js like:

```
---
title: 'some text'
create: '2019-10-23'
---

# some text

some text
```

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "title": "some text",
    "create": "2019-10-23"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "h1",
      "content": "some text"
    },
    {
      "type": "p",
      "content": "some text"
    }
  ]
}
```

There were some pkg i found like `markdown-it`/`showdown` only can make html string.

Comment: `markdown-it`'s `parse` will not generate a html but an array of used tokens. Have you tried that? Maybe you can map your desired structure from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442372/3761628

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tokenize markdown using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041795/how-to-tokenize-markdown-using-node-js)